# One APK that launch a different activity if its mobile or tablet (Android 2.1+)

Tags: android, mobile, manifest, tablet

I've search a lot and don't find the right information for that. I have 2 different activities in my project. At start it was 2 different application, one for mobile and one for tablet. I want to mixe them to get one APK only. So when they where separate it was easy, but mixing the 2 manifest i not for me.I would like to be able to have 2 different activity and the right one launch if this is a mobile and the other if it is a tablet.

Anybody have an example of a manifest that can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you currently have two activities, PhoneActivity and TabletActivity. Create a third activity called SplashActivity. Think of SplashActivity as a splash screen or launcher that is only running for a split second. When your app is launched SplashActivity launches, detects if the device is a phone or tablet and then launches the appropriate activity (PhoneActivity or TabletActivity).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. That's what I need, yeah, but is that possible to do it directly in the manifest. I found that technique that sounds great too : http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/architecting-a-single-apk-app-to-handle-phones-and-tablets-on-android/

I like the Idea of no need to code but simply detect it in the manifest. Problem is that I can't make it works.

Comment: I don't think so. Another option is to ship two different APK's through the same Application in the Market, one for tablets and one for phones

Comment: Actually we have 2 app on Android Market yeah. But you can install the mobile version on tablet and the tablet version on mobile. The name help to distinguish them, but... The mobile version on tablet don't re-size, so at least we can use it. But the tablet version on mobile is not interesting at all.

Comment: What i mean is you can distribute a single "application" through the android market that has multiple APKs backing it. You can configure the market to install certain apks for certain devices and other apks for other devices.

Comment: Didn't know that! I need to take a look at it. Any idea where this information is available? This is very, very interesting!

Comment: @Jffortierqc see this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/multiple-apk-support-in-android-market.html

Comment: Found it ! 
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Thanks for that tricks

Comment: @slayton hello,idea u suggested for having multiple APKs for tablet and phone can be done by using adding `<supports-screens>` in manifest. But issue is large phones likes note 2, grand are picking the tablet apks. Do you have any idea by which we could clearly differentiate apk for phone and tables. Here is link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490503/phones-are-picking-tablet-build-from-android-play-store

Answer (score 6):

To Extend slayton's answer, in the splash (or launcher activity with no interface), you will need to detect whether it is a tablet.  You will need to make you're own determination what is considered a tablet.  I assume that you are thinking of screen size.  Here is a simple example that I got from here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d6323d81f226f93f

It uses the magic screen size > 6 inches to determine it is a tablet.

```
public boolean isTablet() { 
    try { 
        // Compute screen size 
        DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
        float screenWidth  = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi; 
        float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi; 
        double size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) + 
                                Math.pow(screenHeight, 2)); 

        // Tablet devices should have a screen size greater than 6 inches 
        return size >= 6; 
    } catch(Throwable t) { 
        Log.error(TAG_LOG, "Failed to compute screen size", t); 
        return false; 
}
```

Once the launcher activity determines it is a tablet or not, just launch the appropriate activity.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same using this method : http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/architecting-a-single-apk-app-to-handle-phones-and-tablets-on-android/

I like the idea that there no need to create a class that only detect but doing it directly in the manifest. I wanted to implement it, but can't make it works. My manifest must be wrong it always start the first one which is the phone.

Comment: Very cool.  I Didn't know you could do this.  Did you create res/values-sw600dp/bools.xml and reference it in your manifest?  Are you running an OS older than Android 3.2.  Sounds like you need to put the same content in res/values-xlarge/bools.xml to cater for older versions.

Comment: I need it to work on Android 2.1 and more. So res/values-sw600dp/bools.xml won't works. I tried to put the res/values-large/bools.xml, not res/values-xlarge/bools.xml, because I read that xlarge is not supported in 2.1. 

I'm not able to make it works. I'm new to Android development so I'm sure I did something wrong, but what I can't tell. That' why I'm looking for someone who did it.

Comment: @Kevin Hey, I tried this with emulator phones with screen size above 5 inches (5.4 inches) are calculated here as above 6 inches and displayed under tablet. Please help me how to deal with this. It litter urgent.

Comment: I note that the link to demianflannery.wordpress.com now says the technique does not work. Alternative suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

This entry is now old but I've not found the question elsewhere on this site, and I think the advice is probably no longer true - arguably it was not the best even then, but that might not have been apparent.

The best advice is probably in:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

although that is not always clear. I had a similar problem: I've an application that lists some entries (they are dates) and if you click on the dates the phone behaviour is that it switches to a new screen with info for those dates. [OK simplification, but hopefully you get the idea]. The "new screen" is a new activity. I wanted to set the tablet behaviour so that the "new screen" bit was shown to the right or below the list of dates - you'd always see it.

Both activities had been written as standard - without using frameworks. The main change I had to do was to restructure the DetailActivity as a Framework - with a very thin Activity around it. If I'd followed the linked guidelines, I would also have restructured the MainActivity similarly, but so I've not - there is seemingly no actual need to. Instead I've rewritten the MainActivity to handle whether the DetailFragment is present or not - e.g. when you click on the dates, it either updates the fragment directly or creates an intent to open the DetailActivity. The key part of this is the statement:

```
mDetailFragment = (DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
```

which goes in the activity's onCreate() method, after SetContentView(). Key here if the fragment does not exist in the layout, then null is returned - there are then several places in the subsequent code along the lines of "if (mDetailFragment != null)".

With that it is merely a matter of having different layouts for tablets. The now advised approach here is to go on the Smallest Screen Width, so using layout directory layout-sw600dp for the tablet version. Actually in my usecase, I wanted different layouts for landscape (detail to right) and portrait (detail below), so I had separate layout-sw600dp-land and layout-sw600dp-port versions of the main activity layout file.

One knock on from this, and if there is an issue with this approach then this is it, is that other layout files may also need to be duplicated. For example, the layout of the existing DetailsActivity already has different portrait and landscape versions - optimising the screen space. It turns out that if you put the details on the right on a tablet, then the screen space needs the portrait orientation - the space is higher than it is wider. At least that is true for my use. Similarly, the fragment's space when the tablet is held portrait is naturally landscape in shape. To get around this, I copy the fragment_detail.xml file from layout-land to layout-sw600dp-port. If I change one of these files, I have to change both. It would be nice not to have to!