# Phones are picking tablet build from Android play store

Tags: android

I am using two .apk files, one for tablets and one for phones. I am handling them using the Multiple APK Handling document from Google.

In my phone manifest:

```
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"  />
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="false" />
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" />
```

And in my tablet manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" />
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="false" />
```

But now phones like Note2, Grand, Nexus-4 are picking the tablet build.

Please help me in writing the right filters for tablets and phones.

Thanks.

Comment: Your first `<supports-screens>` does not block `large`/`xlarge` devices. You need to use `<compatible-screens>` for that: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps However, if by "Note2" you mean the Galaxy Note 2, that is a `large` device and will use what you erroneously think is the "tablet" app. IMHO, you are *far* better served creating a single app that supports all screen sizes, rather than trying to use multiple APKs.

Comment: @CommonsWare "Your first <supports-screens> does not block large/xlarge devices." Why so, if have declared android:largeScreens="false" && Galaxy Note 2 is a large device but its a phone after all & i want it to work like phone..My application is live & i want to change it ASAP.

Comment: "Why so" -- because Android will automatically scale the app up for `large`/`xlarge` devices. Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps "its a phone after all" -- from the standpoint of screen size, it is not a "phone", and there is nothing that you can do about it. It is `large`, whether you like it or not. The only way you can get it to "work like phone" is to create a **single APK** that supports all screen sizes, at which point you can organize your layouts to treat Note 2-sized screens the same as you do smaller ones.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, Does that mean i can't do anything with current scenario ?  Can't i restrict these device to phone version with additional filters?

Comment: You could prevent the Note 2 from running your app at all by blocking it through the Developer Console. I am not aware that you can use such blocks to somehow force the Note 2 to install a particular version of your APK.

Comment: @CommonsWare android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600", Can this help, if i put this in Tablet version?

Comment: "android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600", Can this help" -- no, as according to docs, it is not used for filtering the Play Store: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#requiresSmallest

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32990/discussion-between-kamal-and-commonsware)

Answer (score 0):

Before trying this. Please **[READ](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)** it fully.

Make Your Layout like this:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

For **TAB**:

For example, if your application is only for tablet-style devices with a 600dp smallest available width:

```
<manifest ... >
<supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
...
</manifest>
```

[**For Tablet**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) . Hope this will help you.