# Google Play: App should be downloadable only from Tablets

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-play

I would like to restrict our app in Mobile phones, it should be downloadable only from tablets not from mobile phone. How can do this?. Can we do it in code level or Is there any option in Google Play Console?.

Currently our app in Beta testing mode.

How can I solve this:

Edit:

I have following code in my manifest.

```
 <supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"/>
```

But still I can able to access my app from google play (Testing mode).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Develop application only for tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185123/develop-application-only-for-tablet)

Comment: Yes, I have the same code in my manifest file. But its not working. Will this code work when the app in test mode(for Internal testers) ?

Comment: firstly, nowadays there is no strict way to determine whether the device is phone or tablet. So how you know if the device is a *tablet*?

Comment: I agree, As per the Google documentation link (https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution#FilteringTabletApps) , I have added this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should be the largestWidthLimitDp for Phone only app (Do not support Tablet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857630/what-should-be-the-largestwidthlimitdp-for-phone-only-app-do-not-support-tablet)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, One option is to restrict screen size support:

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

There is no restriction for tablet. You can declare restriction bsed on screen size only. Please refer to [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution#FilteringTabletApps) for more information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have this code in my manifest but its not working.

Comment: Humor us here. How are you confirming that it doesn't work? A Google Account with only one (incompatible) device in it? That would be what I would trust.

Comment: We have uploaded our app for internal testing in Google Play. Then we tried to access by using handset(Google Pixel 2) and its accessible. So that I raised this query.

Comment: Actually we are accessing the app by using Opt-in URL which is generated during internal testing publish. Do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: The attribute just helps google play filter the apk according to device compatibility I think you would be able to install the apk if you have access to it.

Comment: Hi @a.toraby Thanks. I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

**Android isn't just phones and tablets.**

You should consider why you really want to exclude Tablet support. This is completely your business decision to make, but goes completely against the Android philosophy. There is no clear definition of "phone" or "tablet". What about "[phablets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phablet)"? What about Android TVs? What about Chromebooks? What about Phones docked to computer monitors? What about new devices we haven't even thought about yet?

A helpful way to think about this is "What is it about tablets that means we don't want to target them?"

- if it is the fact they normally don't make phone calls, then require uses-feature [android.hardware.telephony](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) and accept the fact you'll allow tablets that can make phone calls. This will be OK because your business decision is based on the ability to make phone calls.
- If it is the fact they have large screens, then use screen size as targeting. Ruling out phones with large screens will be ok, because the business reason is large screens.

But saying "we don't want to target tablets" without a good technical reason for what it is about tablets you don't want to support is probably a mistake, as there is no technical definition of "tablet" and there are 1000s of weird and wonderful Android devices out there you probably haven't thought about.

In the right hand side menu of the Play Console there is an entry "Device catalogue". This will let you search for different devices and if they don't support your app it will explain why.